# NextGEN Gallery (Wordpress) says that the image file is invalid

Tags: wordpress, image-gallery

After some security updates, the NextGEN Gallery plug-in does not allow for image uploads any more.

When a valid image file is dragged into the upload area and "upload image" is clicked the following error message shows up:

```
Invalid image file. Acceptable formats: JPG, GIF, and PNG.
```

Answer (score 0):

After digging in the plug-in files, and generating some error information, we found that the following line in `is_image_file()` retured `false`

```
@exif_imagetype($filename)
```

The reason was an issue with reading the temporarily uploaded image file, which should have been something like `/tmp/phpABCDEF123`.

The reason for that, again, was the newly set `open_basedir` option for PHP. This disallowed the PHP script to access the directory `/tmp`. The solution was to set a different `upload_tmp_dir` in the Apache site configuration.

```
 php_admin_value open_basedir "/var/www/wordpress"
 php_admin_value upload_tmp_dir "/var/www/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/tmp"
```

**Note:** This new upload/temp directory *must not* allow for execution of PHP files, or you can cause a major security issue.

```
<Directory /var/www/wordpress/wp-content/uploads>
    <Files *.php>
       deny from all
    </Files>
</Directory>
```